# Monitor a cluster of nodes

Tags: python, hadoop, statistics, cluster-computing, monitor

I have > 10 nodes in a cluster. I have installed an Hadoop stack on the cluster using Cloudera (YARN, HBase, Hue, Hadoop FS, Spark, Flink). Is there an easy way to gather global statistics of all of the nodes (in terms of CPU usage, memory usage and network usage) and read it out with Python? The purpose of using Python is that I am completely free to specify the plots and to ensure a uniform plotting style in my report. Which software can I use to accomplish this? It does not have to be distributed, just an easy library would be sufficient.

Comment: I'm using librato.com, it has a very simple integration process to read metrics and show them in a nice dashboard, and also a python module for posting or retrieving data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to consider using **ansible** for this purpose. 
Here's a simple [playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html) that collects some data on hosts specified in [inventory file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) and appends it to a local file:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: your_user
  tasks:
  - name: collect load average
    shell: cat /proc/loadavg
    register: cluster_node_la

  - name: write to local disk
    lineinfile: dest=/tmp/cluster_stat create=yes line="{{ ansible_fqdn }}:{{ cluster_node_la.stdout_lines }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

You can run it as follows: 
    `ansible-playbook -i ansible-inventory stats-playbook.yml --forks=1`

- *ansible_inventory* is the file containing a list of your hosts
- *stats-playbook.yml* is the file printed above

Of course, depending on how you're going to store collected data it might be implemented differently but I think the general idea is clear. Anyway, there are plenty of ways to solve it in **ansible**.

Besides, ansible has python API and you can do most things directly from python! I.e, this is how we can collect configuration of your cluster:

```
import pprint

import ansible.runner
import ansible.inventory

inventory_file = 'ansible_inventory'  # see ansible inventory files
inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(inventory_file)

runner = ansible.runner.Runner(
   module_name='setup',
   module_args='',
   pattern='all',
   inventory=inventory
)

cluster_facts = runner.run()
pprint.pprint(cluster_facts)
```

Comment: That looks great! Thank you :-)